# React native data not rendered after setstate

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

So i have been working with firebase as a backend in my react native application, i have tried to fetch data this way but i have nothing rendered, i have the activity indicator that went off, but i get that the data array is empty in the application screen, and when i do a console.log, i can see the data in the console, but nothing shows off in the application screen, please help me it's been days that i'm struggling.

```
export default class Leaderboard extends React.Component{


constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        loading : true,
        data : []
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    firebase.firestore().collection('rankings').get()
        .then(res => {
            let rankArray = []
            res.forEach(document => {
                rankArray.push(document.data())
            })
            return rankArray;
        }).then(res =>{
            let data = []
            res.forEach(item =>{
                firebase.firestore().doc(item.idUser.path)                    
                .get()
                    .then(doc =>{
                        let dataItem = {}
                        dataItem.id = doc.ref.path
                        dataItem.name = doc.data().fullname
                        dataItem.points = doc.data().points
                        dataItem.lc = 'Oran'
                        data.push(dataItem)
                        dataItem = {}

            })
        })
        return data;
    }).then(res =>this.setState({
        loading : false,
        data : res
    })  ).catch(err => console.log(err))


}


render(){

if(this.state.loading){
        return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator size= 'large'></ActivityIndicator>
        </View>
        )
}else{
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.data.length}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                 renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.fullname}</Text>}
            />

        </View>
    )

}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this not working as expected is that you're trying to perform an asynchronous function call, per iteration of your `res` array inside of your `forEach()` callback:

```
 // This is asynchronous
 firebase.firestore().doc(item.idUser.path).get().then(doc =>{ ... })
```

Consider revising your code to use the `Promise.all()` method instead. This will ensure that each asynchronous for individual documents per-item in `res` array is completed, before `setState()` in the susequent `.then()` handler is invoked:

```
.then(res => {
        let rankArray = []
        res.forEach(document => {
            rankArray.push(document.data())
        })
        return rankArray;
})
.then(res => {

  // Use promise all to resolve each aync request, per item in the 
  // res array
  return Promise.all(res.map(item => {

    // Return promise from .get().then(..) for this item of res array.
    return firebase.firestore()
    .doc(item.idUser.path)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {

      let dataItem = {}
      dataItem.id = doc.ref.path
      dataItem.name = doc.data().fullname
      dataItem.points = doc.data().points
      dataItem.lc = 'Oran'

      // Return resolve dataItem to array that is relayed to next .then()
      // handler (ie where you call this.setState())
      return dataItem
    })
  }));
})
.then(res =>this.setState({
    loading : false,
    data : res
}))
```